# Setting values without instantiating a new object

Tags: javascript

What I am trying to do is be easily explain from the code.

How can I achieve in getting the correct result without creating a new object every time?

```
    var optionsArr = new Array();
    var labelObj = new Object();
    labelObj.label = 'Pink';
    labelObj.value = "Pink1";
    optionsArr.push(labelObj);

    labelObj.label = 'Green';
    labelObj.value = "Green2";
    optionsArr.push(labelObj);

    console.log('optionsArr' + JSON.stringify(optionsArr));

expected result :  {"label":"Pink","value":"Pink1"},{"label":"Green","value":"Green2"}


actual result :  {"label":"Green","value":"Green2"},{"label":"Green","value":"Green2"}
```

Comment: you, by definition, need a new object each time. you can't have one object that has two different values for `label` based on which index in the array it is at.

Comment: One way or the other a second object needs to be created. You cannot have one object have different property values at the same time. In JavaScript, objects are reference-type values, so assigning a new value to a property does not create a copy of the object, it mutates the exiting object.

Comment: Put another way, if you want your array to contain two objects, you need to, at the very least, create two objects. Otherwise, your array will instead just refer to the same object twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var obj = [];
obj[0] = {"label" : "Pink","value" : "Pink1"};
obj[1] = {"label" : "Green","value" : "Green1"};

alert(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

OR the more proper way to handle an array:

```js
var obj = [];

obj.push({
  label: 'Green',
  value: 'Green2'
});

obj.push({
  label: 'Pink',
  value: 'Pink1'
});

alert(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Comment: Or even better: `var obj = [{"label" : "Pink","value" : "Pink1"}, {"label" : "Green","value" : "Green1"}]`.

Comment: @FelixKling I guess the best solution is based on how the OP is generating this information. If it's in a loop or if its manually entered in.

Comment: So this is exactly what i'm kind of looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

In JavaScript objects are reference-type values, so there is no way to pass object value except for creating a new object, so you're limited to [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) option. The approach below would change desired properties and copy other ones:

```js
var optionsArr = new Array();
var labelObj = new Object();

labelObj.label = 'Pink';
labelObj.value = "Pink1";
optionsArr.push(labelObj);

// Use Object.assign() to update only some of properties
optionsArr.push(Object.assign({}, labelObj, {
  label: 'Green',
  value: 'Green2'
}));

// Original object would remain unchaged
optionsArr.push(labelObj);

console.log('optionsArr' + JSON.stringify(optionsArr));
```

Comment: You are mixing "pass **by** reference" with passing **a** reference. These are not the same things. JavaScript is a "pass by *value*" language that implements objects as *reference-type* values. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_type_and_reference_type . Or in other words: You are using the wrong terminology for the behavior your are describing.